# Restkit Kit XML Mapping Objects Returns null

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, restkit

Working on `Restkit` and used `XML` as response now mapping with my custom class buy `Content_Doc` inner the tags value returing `null`. is there any problem in `mapping` Please help

XML

```
<Contents>
    <Content>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Times Now</name>
        <designer>YES</designer>
            <Content_Docs>
                 <Content_Doc>
                    <id>110</id>
                    <name>Home Owner</name>
                    <photo>112</photo>
                </Content_Doc>
                <Content_Doc>
                    <id>110</id>
                    <name>Home Owner</name>
                    <photo>112</photo>
                </Content_Doc>
                <Content_Doc>
                    <id>110</id>
                    <name>Home Owner</name>
                    <photo>112</photo>
                </Content_Doc>
            </Content_Docs>
    </Content>
</Contents>
```

and i mapped this using

```
RKObjectMapping* contentMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Content class]];
    [contentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:
            @{@"id.text" : @“conID”,@“name.text" : @"name"}];

RKObjectMapping* Content_DocsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Content_Docs class]];
    [authorMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:
            @{@"id.text" : @"subDocId",@"name.text" : @"name"}];

  [contentMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Content_Docs.Content_Doc" toKeyPath:@"Content_Doc" withMapping:authorMapping]];
```

can anyone please review

Answer (score 0):

I don't use XML much, but it looks like the relationship should just be:

```
... relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Content_Docs" ...
```